# SVN failing to create SASL context

Tags: ubuntu, subversion, sasl

Trying to execute the command

```
svn log svn://[my server address]/path/to/repository
```

nets me the following:

```
svn: E170001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://[my server address]/path/to/repository'
svn: E170001: Could not create SASL context: generic failure
```

Some quick googling reveals a possible [solution](http://forums.cpanel.net/f34/how-do-i-enable-port-linux-38362.html):

```
sudo port activate cyrus-sasl2 @2.1.23_3+kerberos
```

However, before I attempt this, I would like to know a couple things.

1. What exactly is going on?
2. What does this command do? How does it fix the problem?

EDIT: I am not using SASL, nor do I wish to. I don't actually have Cyrus SASL installed.

Comment: You're on Ubuntu, does the `port` command actual exist there? I didn't see it on 12.10.

Comment: BTW, `port` is an OSX command for the ports package manager, so that isn't your issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue with these particular versions of the cyrus-sasl2 libraries. Try updating to a newer version of the libraries and/or downgrade to an older version if the latest does not resolve your issue.

I found the following issues that were raised regarding this issue in both a Fedora bug tracker as well as a Debian one.

- [subversion: not working at all SASL context error](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=683555)
- [Bug 888775 - svn: E170001: Could not create SASL context: generic failure](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=888775)

Comment: Does SVN run through cyrus-sasl2 regardless? Because I have SASL disabled on the server....

Comment: @MirroredFate - read the SASL section of the manual. Your server is the one advertising this: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html

Comment: It says to activate SASL you have to have the line `use-sasl = true`, which I have commented out.... The only security I have the server configured to use is the `CRAM-MD5`.... which is why I am so confused....